# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, php exec laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, exec

I am facing and issue when executing .js file in my server. but it actually working well in my 2 computers. I googled for few days but cannot find much info & no solutions.

[image: Here is the Screenshot]
Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: try giving the full path upto the node folder such as `exec('C:/laragon/www/ezicuci.com/public/node/node example.js', $out, $error)`

Comment: Is node even installed on the server?

Comment: Also, don't post screenshots of code. Copy/paste it directly into your question instead. Images aren't searchable. And if the image server goes down for a bit, the question won't make any sense.

Comment: It just sounds like node.exe isn't in your path on one computer such that it can be executed from anywhere.

Comment: you just need to install node and set it in your path. An answer readily available on proper searching.